# Remove default text from Symfony submit button

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-forms

This is my button which should be just icon without text

```
{{ form_widget(form.submit, { 'attr': {'class': 'fa fa-search'} }) }}
```

I tried also to set value in **FormType**

```
->add('submit', 'submit', array(
                'label' => '',
                'attr' => array(
                    'value' => ''
                )
            ))
```

But nothing happen, or to say better, button contain

> Submit

default text

Comment: you could remove the submit form button definition from the formtype and add it via simply html element `<input class="my-class" type="submit" value="">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to set the label to false:

```
->add('submit', 'submit', array(
    'label' => false,
    'attr' => array(
        'value' => ''
    )
))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use "space" for label attribute value. It's not "fair" way, as your button still has one "space", but i used to use it:

```
{{ form_widget(form.submit, {
                            'label' : ' ',
                            'attr': {
                                'class': 'fa fa-search'}
                            })
                        }}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can replace:

```
{{ form_widget(form.submit, { 'attr': {'class': 'fa fa-search'} }) }}
```

by:

```
<button class="fa fa-search"></button>
```

And don't add the submit button by code.